# PHP Search Function not executing scripting

Tags: php, search

I have a problem with my PHP script I have a search bar but when I redirect it to the class instead of running the script it shows me the PHP script. I am new to the OOP PHP programming style.

I am trying to achieve a really simple OOP search query on my database. But I am confused as to why it re-directs me to classes/class.House.inc rather than executing the script. Where am I going wrong?

I've tried looking online for a OOP tutorial online but had little luck :( Any help would be welcomed!

index.php

```
    <form method="post" action="classes/class.House.inc" name="search" id="searchform">
    <input type="text" name="term" id="searchinput"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value=""/>
    </form>
```

classes/class.House.inc

```
   <?php 

   class House extends Database {

    public function search (){

            $query = "SELECT * FROM houses WHERE postcode like '%$term%'";

                    $result = $this->mysqli->query($query);

                    $num_result = $result->num_rows;    
                    if($num_result > 0){
                        while($rows =$result->fetch_assoc()){               
                            $this->data[]=$rows;
                            //print_r($rows);
                        header ("Location: ../search.php");
                        }           
                        return $this->data;
                }}}
    ?>
```

search.php

```
    <table width="500" border="1" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
      <th width="16" scope="row">id</th>
      <td width="95">bedrooms</td>
      <td width="140">description</td>
      <td width="104">roadname</td>
       <td width="71">postcode</td>
    </tr>
  <?php
        $obj = new House();
        $obj->search();
        foreach($obj->data as $val){
      extract($val);
      ?>
<tr>
<td scope="row"><?php echo $id; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $bedrooms; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $description; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $roadname; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $postcode; ?></td>
    </tr>
      <?php
  }
  ?>
  </table>
```

Comment: Have you read the [PHP manual on OOP](http://php.net/oop)? You can't re-direct to a .inc file. It has to be .php.

Comment: `class.House.inc` this should be `class.House.inc.php`

Comment: Why you extend your DB class ? can't you just load it in one variable protected $DB; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the index.php fix the form

```
 <form method="post" action="search.php" name="search" id="searchform">
```

and at search.php add this line

```
<?php
        require("classes/class.House.inc");
        $obj = new House();
        $obj->search();
        foreach($obj->data as $val){
        extract($val);
?>
```

and why the script display that because apache configuration you need to put inc file as script excusable

Comment: excusable? I think you mean executable :) However, we'll excuse your typo :)